# Remove superuser/sudo requirement for certain applications/commands

Tags: linux, sudo

I use Debian and I wish to remove superuser/sudo requirements for certain applications, among them iotop and radeontop. I have tried using visudo as mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/235084/how-do-i-remove-ubuntus-password-requirement but it did not work surprisingly. Thanks.

Comment: The question you linked is to run commands using sudo but without password, not without sudo

Comment: @pim Looks like I got the wrong solution then, do you know the right method of solving the problem?

Comment: If you find too tiresome to type `sudo iotop`, you can try to make an alias or a shell script containing `sudo iotop`...

Comment: @pim I wish to involve the applications/commands in certain automated scripts so having to type the password would be problematic and interrupt the process.

Comment: Please have a look at this one : https://askubuntu.com/a/159009/454520

Comment: There is a difference between not using different - hard - and using dufo without a password - which can be configured in dudoers

Comment: @davidgo Hi, I guess what I'm looking for is completely removing the requirement from the application user/system-wide.